# What type of asymptote is there, if any, in a rational function where the numerator's degree is 2 or more than the denominators?

Tags: rational-functions

It is known that there is a slant (oblique) asymptote when the degree of the numerator is 1 more than the denominator in a rational function.

To find the equation of this asymptote, you simply divide the denominator into the numerator to yield a linear function which expresses the oblique asymptote.

Consider the function 
$$\dfrac{x^4-16}{x^2-2x}$$

Dividing the two, you end up with the quadratic function $$x^2+2x+4$$

Graphing the two, you can see the parabola certainly behaves like an asymptote in relation to the original rational function.

So, is this an asymptote, or, something else?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the function as
$$\frac{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+4)}{x(x-2)}=\frac{(x+2)(x^2+4)}x=x^2+2x+4+\frac8x.$$
This shows the parabola $y=x^2+2x+4$ is a curvilinear asymptote to the given curve.